# Using IF, VLookup, to send automatic Emails in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, email, vlookup

I created a spreadsheet that automatically updates its data based on prices from the web. I need to write a code in VBA that looks for prices (would be okay for it to be just one cell) to reach a certain number and once it hits that number to send an email notification to  specified addresses. I have a general idea of how to approach this but since I'm new to VBA I'm pretty lost when it comes to the errors I'm getting and how to fix them. Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If (VLookup(B248, B248, 1, False)) = 30 Then
            Sub Send_Email_Using_VBA()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
    Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
    Email_Subject = "Price Alert"
    Email_Send_From = "email@address.com"
    Email_Send_To = "email1@address.com"
    Email_Cc = "email2@address.com"
    Email_Body = "Price higher than XX"
    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail_Single
    .Subject = Email_Subject
    .To = Email_Send_To
    .cc = Email_Cc
    .Body = Email_Body
    .send
    End With
    debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description


    End Sub
```

I apologize if this is completely butchered and I'd appreciate any input, this has been driving me up the wall.

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting and on which lines?

Comment: Its highlighting (VLookup) and giving me a compile error: sub or function not defined

Answer (score 0):

`VLookup` is not a VBA function but a worksheet function that can be used like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()
```

You'll need to incorporate some error handling though as an error will be thrown if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target = 30 Then
        Call Send_Email_Using_VBA(Target.Offset(0, -1))
    End If
End If

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub Send_Email_Using_VBA(strItem as variant)

Dim Email_Subject As String, Email_Send_From As String, Email_Send_To As String, _
Email_Cc As String, Email_Bcc As String, Email_Body As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

Email_Subject = "Price Alert"
Email_Send_From = "email@address.com"
Email_Send_To = "email1@address.com"
Email_Cc = "email2@address.com"
Email_Body = "Price of " & strItem & " higher than XX"

On Error GoTo debugs

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

With Mail_Single
    .Subject = Email_Subject
    .To = Email_Send_To
    .cc = Email_Cc
    .Body = Email_Body
    .send
End With

debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

How about something like this? First of all, Vlookup is a worksheet function and not a VBA function (some functions are both). So you would have to use it like

```
Application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(etc.)
```

However, Target is the cell that has changed on the worksheet, so use that.

IF statements need to either be on one line or need to end in an 'End If'.

To call another sub, use 'Call' rather than 'Sub' as that would define a new sub. Then you have to make that sub.

I've assumed that the item name is in the column to the left of the price, so I've made the Call pass the contents of the cell to the left of the one that has reached 30 to the Send sub. If you don't want that then take it out.

I haven't tested the email part, but the rest should work.

Do you only want to send an email once per item? Or once in total? Also, what if the price goes from e.g. 29 to 31? Will that happen?

Comment: Thanks again, I just need to notify once it reaches or goes above the price, its going to be running in the background so maybe it would be best for me to get it to notify whenever it hits right on the number to make sure I catch it on both sides or would it recognize each time it surpasses the value.

Comment: Also on what line do I specify the cell in question? I see you set call to pass the contents but I'm not seeing it in the code.

Comment: Target is whichever cell has changed, so once a cell changes, the worksheet_change sub checks if it's 30. Then if it is, it passes the cell to the left to the email sub, which uses it in the email body.

Comment: Alright thanks, When I try to run it I get a run error (13) and when I select debug it highlight the If Target = 30 Then line. Any idea what that's about.

Comment: If you only want to check a certain cell, or column you could instead do:

    "If Target = 30 And Target.Address = [B1].Address"

or

    "If Target = 30 And Target.column = 2"

for example

Comment: 13 is type mismatch. You could try 'If Target.value = 30' perhaps. I'm not sure why that is happening though, as it should still work

Edit: Ah, I've changed the if statement now. It needs to only evaluate the value if one cell changes

Comment: Great I'm error free for now. Can I specify which cell it reacts to?

Comment: Yeah, e.g.  "If Target = 30 And Target.Address = [B1].Address" for cell B1